# Why is the c function `open` ~4x slower on MacOS vs. an Ubuntu VM on the same machine?

Tags: c, macos, ubuntu, filesystems, fcntl

Why is MacOS ~4x slower to open files than an Ubuntu VM on the same machine here?

A MWE using similar settings to the code this behavior was discovered on

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
    struct timespec tstart={0,0}, tend={0,0};
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tstart);

    int fd = open("/path/to/testfile.txt", O_RDONLY | O_CLOEXEC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH);

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tend);
    printf("%.0f µs\n", (((double)tend.tv_sec + 1.0e-9*tend.tv_nsec) - ((double)tstart.tv_sec + 1.0e-9*tstart.tv_nsec)) * 1.0e6);

   return 0;
}
```

MacOS 10.15.7, no SIP, no file vault, on a MacBook Pro with an SSD

```
51 µs
46 µs
49 µs
30 µs
46 µs
```

Ubuntu 20.04 VM (parallels) on the same machine

```
12 µs
12 µs
12 µs
13 µs
13 µs
```

Comment: I'm guessing the VM's file system is in DRAM. Either that, or the VM's file system is just a lot smaller (fewer directory entries to search through while resolving `/path/to/`).

Comment: Interesting. Would there be a particular path I could place the file at that would bypass the resolve time? /aaaa.txt?

Comment: Why are you even comparing two different operating systems running two different kernels in two different environments (different libraries, different kind of executables, etc)? Comparing those numbers is meaningless.

Comment: Good question. I'm trying to figure out why reading of small files is significantly slower on MacOS than Ubuntu for an application that is shipped cross-OS. I hoped this VM setup would be illustrative of where the hardware was unquestionably the same, but the DRAM question has thrown that into question.

Answer (score 1):

The time spent in the `open` function is unlikely to have anything to do with the disk or backing filesystem type; rather, it's mainly a matter of the operating system's implementation of system calls, and perhaps in particular its model of filesystem abstractions. Linux is a monolithic kernel without different privilege domains or memory spaces involved, and aims to make system calls very fast. At least originally MacOS X was built on the microkernel stuff Apple has been a fan of for decades, and if it's still anything like that, system calls are probably a lot more costly. They may even hook into antivirus software or stuff like that nowadays.

Comment: https://sigpipe.macromates.com/2020/macos-catalina-slow-by-design/ Lots of hooks, not all of which can be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

A Linux VM being faster than native MacOS appears to be explained by https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28739#issuecomment-1042652785

> Just FWIW, this is a problem with Apple NVMe drives (T2 and M1 Macs alike). Their cache flush performance is abysmal. This affects both macOS and (native) Linux (presumably existing VM solutions fail to forward this as F_FULLSYNC if they run faster). You get about 46 IOPS of F_FULLSYNC on macOS on an M1 machine, and about the same on native Linux with fsync().